# Netty, Android| IO event polling frequency

Tags: android, multithreading, netty

I'm calling a netty's thread from external thread, using netty's context. 
I encountered some significant delay between "pipeline write" and the actual write (inside the handler), called by netty.

To clarify: 
The external thread calls: context.pipeline().write(Object obj) 
and following, netty's thread calls "write" on handler:
@Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise)

I've observed about 40 millis of delay between the two commands. I assume it is related to netty's pipeline polling frequency.

1. is it possible to change netty's polling frequency? (is it eventloop or channel config?)
2. are there any other possible reasons for this kind of delay?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try context.pipeline().write**AndFlush**(Object obj) ?

Comment: Thanks. tried, nothing changed :(